# 500 internal server error when adding updating product Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been having an ongoing frustrating server error on my wordpress site -  it appears to be Woocommerce related as it always happens when I try to edit or add a new product.

Can anyone begin to shed some light on what this means from my error log?!

```
[Tue May 13 09:31:58 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: 

/home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 09:31:58 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 09:32:12 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 10:41:18 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 10:41:19 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 10:45:39 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/
[Tue May 13 10:45:39 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 10:45:45 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/
[Tue May 13 10:54:25 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:54:25 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:54:31 2014] [warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
[Tue May 13 10:54:32 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:54:32 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:54:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:54:43 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:55:04 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:55:04 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:55:23 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:55:26 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:57:03 2014] [warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
[Tue May 13 10:57:09 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:57:09 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:57:42 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:57:42 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 10:57:45 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 10:57:45 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 11:02:55 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:02:55 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_brand&post_type=product
[Tue May 13 11:03:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:03:43 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_brand&post_type=product
[Tue May 13 11:05:03 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:05:03 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/shop/
[Tue May 13 11:15:45 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:15:45 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:17:01 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:17:01 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:17:03 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:17:03 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:17:04 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 11:21:53 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:21:53 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:21:53 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 11:22:08 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:22:08 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:23:01 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:23:01 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:23:55 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 11:23:55 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 11:23:55 2014] [error] [client 74.208.134.21] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 11:30:36 2014] [error] [client 213.171.217.184] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 11:30:37 2014] [error] [client 213.171.217.184] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue May 13 12:02:30 2014] [warn] (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
[Tue May 13 12:03:07 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:03:07 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
[Tue May 13 12:23:21 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:23:21 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:23:40 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:23:40 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:23:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:23:43 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:23:46 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:23:46 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:23:56 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:23:56 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:24:02 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:24:02 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi, referer: http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit
[Tue May 13 12:27:05 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:27:05 2014] [warn] (110)Connection timed out: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
[Tue May 13 12:30:01 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:30:01 2014] [error] [client 88.208.252.80] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:30:01 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:30:01 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:39:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:39:51 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:40:14 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:40:32 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:40:35 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:40:38 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WC_Payment_Gateway' not found in /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/dev/wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php on line 161
[Tue May 13 12:41:53 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:41:53 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:42:06 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:42:06 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:43:55 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:43:55 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:46:57 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:46:57 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:47:23 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:47:23 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:47:47 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:47:47 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:48:02 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Tue May 13 12:48:02 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] Premature end of script headers: php54-cgi
[Tue May 13 12:48:02 2014] [error] [client 193.111.227.10] File does not exist: /home/linnas01/i/integralvitality.co.uk/user/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Once the error happens there is nothing I can do, it seems the database is not recoverable. Tried changing the name of the plugins folder, and each time I try dropping the database tables to import the backup sql file but nothing works. I have to create another database and import the backup which restores the site. I can then click around in woocommmerce in the back end until I try updating a product which does the same all over again!

The hosting technical support is absolutely appalling! This has been going on for 3 weeks and they can't seem to tell me if it's their error or not :(

Comment: The issue is in sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway plugin. Have you tried reinstalling this from its provider / updating it to the latest version? What version of the plugin and what version of woo are you using?

Comment: I did wonder that as I spotted it in the error log, but this has been happening on and off for a couple of weeks - I only installed it yesterday. I've just deactivated and re activated all of my plugins on the restored site and now I can update products without this crash again! I'm using Woo version 2.1.5 btw

Comment: I've now received the most informative (!) reply from them so far which says this: 'The error logs you have provided suggest a time out error which have been caused by the MySQL 9 server database high load issues. The database server causes your website to load slowly and resulted as time out errors on these logs. We do apologise for this inconvenience and any delay this has caused to you and your business.' Could be the case judging from these error logs or does it seem like they don't really know? They sound pretty clueless on the phone...

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear a newly set up woo commerce is ok, but once you add to it you get those errors?

In looking at the errors some are fairly harmless like a missing favicon icon.  Others are timeouts, and the others are scripts that are just aborting (assuming related to the database time outs).

Without knowing more (hosting, database used, etc) I would suggest that you have support set it up for you, then have them add a few products and then take it over from there.  Though they may not be able to help, perhaps they can just DO it to get you going and you can revisit after the fact?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply :) 
Well I haven't newly set it up. I've just been creating a new database then importing my backup sql db which obviously has the products still in there. It's when I edit them it happens again. So would you suggest that I should try again with a new database and delete all traces of woocommerce?
I noticed the favicon icons missing, I assumed that wouldn't be responsible for such a crash?!

Comment: This time I've managed to restore the database actually without having to create a new one for the first time. Here is the dev site running
http://integralvitality.co.uk/dev/ with the 4 products in. I can make test payments to sagepay etc and everything else. I know as soon as I edit a product the same will happen though!